# How to Uninstall apps or move apps around

Tags: iphone

When I hold my apps down the x does not appear where I can delete apps or move them around I have an iPhone 6s

Comment: have you tried this with multiple apps?  I get this same behavior but with only a few apps. Most work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should either hold your thumb on the app(s) firmer or softer. What happens when you do it now?

If it opens a menu with options or simply a menu that allows you to share the app, you're pushing too hard and actually doing Force Touch.

If it just sort of wiggles but the X doesn't show up and everything stands still again when you release, then you're not pushing enough and it's just not doing anything.

Best of luck.

Answer (score -2):

Additionally: Apple's own and preinstalled Apps like Mail, Safari, etc cannot be deleted. I personally solved this by just shoving them over to a screen in the very back so they're out of my sight.